# Assumptions with proof of sin(a+b)

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

[image]

Hey,

I'm studying trig, and one of the proofs we are doing is of sin(a+b). I use a unit circle, and would draw these lines on, such that P and Q lie on the circle. I feel like there is a big assumption. Why is OQP a right angle?

Comment: Its a part of the proof. First $OQP$ is constructed as a right triangle. Then perpendicular $PR$ is dropped on $OL$. Not the other way round!

Comment: How I am drawing it is using a unit circle, and drawing two lines whose angles are "a" and "a+b" with the x axis.Then i connect the points where the lines cross the circle. I don't understand why this is a right angle.

Comment: It *won't* be.  You are interpreting the proof wrong somehow.

Comment: The way I see the diagram is this: P is on the unit circle.  Q is *not* on the circle but inside the circle.  Q is defined by being an angle of B from the x-axis and either OQ = $\cos A<1$ or that $QP$ is a perpendicular to $OP$ (both are equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ and $Q$ both lie on the circle, $OPQ$ is an isoceles triangle and $OQP$ *cannot* be right.

Anyway, it is more than likely that in the proof, $Q$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ and doest *not* lie on the circle.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking

Comment: @Vasya: see my update.

Comment: Or it could be that $Q$ is defined to so that $OQ = \cos A < 1$ (so Q is interior to the circle).  Either way: If $P$ is on the circle, then $OPQ$ is right angle if and only if $OQ = \cos A$.

Comment: @fleablood: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Addition_Formula_for_Sines#About_the_Diagram

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the proof went nor how you should interpet it.

Interpret it this way instead.

1) Construct a unit circle centered at $O$.

2) Let $P$ be a point of the circle so that the angle of $P$ with the x-axis is the angle $A + B$.

3) Construct the line, $L_1$ through the origin at an angle of $B$. (If you want you can find the point $Z$ where $L_1$ intersects the circle but that point will not be relevant to the proof.)

4) Construct the point $Q$ on $L_1$ so that $PQ$ is perpendicular to $L_1$.

As $OQP$ is a right triangle and $OP =1$ and $QOP = (A+B) - B = A$, we know that $OQ = \cos A < 1$ and so $Q$ is *not* on the circle (unless $A=0$ in which case the result is trivial).  We also know that $PQ = \sin A$.

5) Construct points $R$ (on the x-axis), $S$ (on the x-axis) so that $PR$ and $QS$ are perpendicular to the x-axis.

6) Construct $T$ on $PR$ so that $QT$ is perpendicular to $PR and parallel to the x-axis.

Angle chase to get the illustration as you have it.